# Valor padrão em Spinner + gerados do banco

Tags: java, android

Tenho um spinner que puxa os valores do banco, mas gostaria de deixá-lo sem nada selecionado ou valor padrão:

```
public void spinnerClientes() {
        ControllerClientes ctClientes = new ControllerClientes(this);
        ArrayList<ArrayCliente> clientes = ctClientes.getClientes();
        clientes.add(new ArrayCliente(0, "Selecione..."));
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, clientes);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnClientes.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

O problema é que tentando criar o valor padrão `clientes.add(new ArrayCliente(0, "Selecione..."));` esse valor é adicionado somente no final da lista.

Também já tentei dessa forma, mas não gera o valor porque é substituído:

```
ArrayList<ArrayCliente> clientes = ArrayList<>();
clientes.add(new ArrayCliente(0, "Selecione..."));
clientes = ctClientes.getClientes();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deverá primeiro adicionar o item "Selecione..." e depois o retorno do método `getClientes()` usando [addAll()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20E%3E)).

```
public void spinnerClientes() {
    ControllerClientes ctClientes = new ControllerClientes(this);
    ArrayList<ArrayCliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
    clientes.add(new ArrayCliente(0, "Selecione..."));
    clientes.addAll(ctClientes.getClientes());           
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, clientes);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnClientes.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, mas achei a forma do @Isac mais prática ! Obrigado !

Comment: Eventualmente mais prática mas com menos performance :).

Comment: Então vou usar dessa forma, 1 item a menos pra diminuir performance !

Answer (score 1):

Dando apenas outra alternativa à solução do @ramaral, pode utilizar um *overload* do método `Add` que estava a utilizar que recebe também a posição onde vai adicionar.

A assinatura desse método é `add(int index,E element)`, em que `index` é a posição e `element` é o elemento a adicionar.

No seu código ficaria assim:

```
public void spinnerClientes() {
    ControllerClientes ctClientes = new ControllerClientes(this);
    ArrayList<ArrayCliente> clientes = ctClientes.getClientes();
    clientes.add(0, new ArrayCliente(0, "Selecione..."));
    //-----------^ adicionar na posição 0 do array de clientes
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, clientes);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnClientes.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

[Documentação para o `add(int index,E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E))

Comment: Funcionando ! Obrigado !